# How to connect to Sql Server 2008 database from Visual Basic 6?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-string

What is the correct connection string and what are the requirements for connecting to Sql Server 2008 database from Visual Basic 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
' Initialize variables.
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim provStr As String

' Specify the OLE DB provider.
cn.Provider = "sqloledb"

' Specify connection string on Open method.
ProvStr = "Server=MyServer;Database=northwind;Trusted_Connection=yes"
cn.Open provStr
```

For illustration only ([Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264566%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).):

```
Set rsOrders = New Recordset
rsOrders.Open "Select * from orders", cn
Do While Not rsOrders.EOF
    '
    ' If the order matches some custom business logic then get the details for
    ' that order, without opening a new connection.
    '
    If SomeBusinessLogic(rsOrders("CustomerID")) Then
        Dim rsDetails As Recordset
        Set rsDetails = New Recordset
        '
        ' Open a new recordset using the same connection. Normally it's not
        ' possible to have two recordsets simultaniously using the same
        ' connection, but MARS makes this possible
        '
        rsDetails.Open "Select sum(quantity * unitprice) as total " & _
            "from [order details] " & _
            "where OrderID=" & rsOrders("OrderID"), _
            cn
        grandTotal = grandTotal + rsDetails("total")
    End If
    rsOrders.MoveNext
Loop

lblTotalOrders = grandTotal
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use [ADODB](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/24677-connecting-to-a-sql-server-database-using-adodb/). And here are some [connection string samples](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008).

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Cnn.Open Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=10.1.100.1;Database=DataJualLama;Uid=sa;Pwd=sa;
```

It required to install sql server 2008 native client runtime from microsoft site.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!